# data formating of .csv file with powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have one .csv file in following format with repeated data set as shown below
input file in after opening in notepad format

```
IpAddress        : 163.157.216.45,30.254.45.45
Name             : HRDFSCSCBA005.corp.kkk.net
RegistrationTime : 6/19/2021 12:06:26 AM +00:00
LastSeenDateTime : 6/19/2021 12:06:26 AM +00:00



IpAddress        : 163.157.22.78,30.254.70.78
Name             : hhgdsrfsv060.corp.kkk.net
RegistrationTime : 6/19/2021 5:21:25 AM +00:00
LastSeenDateTime : 6/19/2021 5:21:25 AM +00:00



IpAddress        : 163.157.22.16,30.254.70.16
Name             : kautyeee003.corp.kkk.net
RegistrationTime : 5/19/2021 2:04:40 PM +00:00
LastSeenDateTime : 7/12/2021 10:15:30 AM +00:00
```

[image: input]

and I need following output with powershell script. Please help with power shell script. Any help appreciated
[image]

Comment: your data doesn't seem to be formatted as CSV data.

Comment: @bluff  I have source data coming in that format

Comment: @KawaljeetSingh Can you show us the raw text in the source file? Open the file in `notepad.exe`  and copy paste a sample [into your original post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68376647/edit)

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen added some more data in notepad format

Comment: @KawaljeetSingh Thanks, did you produce this file (which is NOT a csv file by the way) by piping some output directly to `Set-Content` or `Out-File` instead of using `Export-Csv`? If so, you probably want to fix that

Comment: Actually I am getting a file from a system with .csv extension and when I am opening the file with notepad its looking like the screen print which I have shared as first image.

Comment: and I want output as shared in last screen print....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you show is certainly not a CSV structured data file. Perhaps once it was, but it looks like someone has output it into a different format and saved that as file (with extension .csv)

You *can* parse this all out to recreate a workable true CSV file like below:

```
# read the data as single multiline string and split into data blocks on the multi newlines
$rawData = (Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\theInputData.csv' -Raw) -split '(\r?\n){2,}' | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' }

# loop over these data blocks and convert it into objects
$result = $rawData | ForEach-Object {
    # you could use ConvertFrom-StringData like this:
    # $_ -replace '(?m)^([^:]*):(.*)', '$1=$2' | ConvertFrom-StringData
    # but that outputs the data as unordered Hashtable.

    # by splitting and adding to an ordered Hashtable, we can keep the data
    # in the same order it is presented in the input file
    $hash = [ordered]@{}
    foreach ($line in ($_ -split '\r?\n')) {
        $key, $value = ($line -split ':',2).Trim()
        $hash[$key] = $value
    }
    # output the data as object to be collected in variable $result
    [PsCustomObject]$hash
}

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to csv file you can double-click to open in Excel
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\theNewData.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

You now have a proper CSV file you can simply double-click to open in Excel which will look like this:

[image]

Comment: wow!!!, this is what I was looking for....great!!!. Many thanks Theo :-)